# Variable has incomplete type 'CvCapture'

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I'm pretty new to Xcode so I apologize if this is a very simple question. I'm trying to get the OpenCV Xcode sample code to compile and run, but I've been running into a lot of errors.The first problems were all about locating files so I changed the paths to fix this. Unfortunately after fixing those there's now another one that I don't know how to fix. The line of code:

CvCapture pCapture = 0;

produces an error, "Variable has incomplete type 'CvCapture'."
I've made sure that CcCapture is defined so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm currently using Xcode 4.6. If you have any experience with Xcode or OpenCV and know how to fix this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't forget to include the appropriate **header file**. Also, `CvCapture` is not a number, can't initialize it to zero. Where you trying to create a pointer? `CvCapture* pCapture = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
CvCapture* pCapture = 0;
```

because

> ```
> typedef struct CvCapture CvCapture;
> The structure CvCapture does not have public interface and is used only
> as a parameter for video capturing functions.
> ```

http://www.ai.rug.nl/vakinformatie/pas/content/Highgui/opencvref_highgui.htm#highgui_video